# PDO cannot connect if password contains spaces

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I am making a PHP website using PDO with PHP but my DSN (for Postgresql) isn't connecting to the database while with Mysql is working fine.

I am trying with the password `a b c`.

> Error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] missing "=" after "b" in connection info string' in /var/www/owncloud/pg_test.php:11
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /var/www/owncloud/pg_test.php(11): PDO->__construct('pgsql:dbname=te...', 'test', 'a b c')
>       #1 {main}
>       it's working!

[Example code](https://gist.github.com/3046155):

```
<?php

/** createuser -d -R -S -P test
* => set password to "a b c"
*/

$dsn = "pgsql:dbname=test;host=localhost";
$user = "test";
$psw = "a b c";
try{
  $db = new PDO($dsn,$user,$psw);
  echo "Oh gosh!\n";
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo "Error :" . $e."\n";
}

$e_user = addslashes($user);
$e_password = addslashes($psw);
$psw = $user = null;
$dsn .= ";user='$e_user';password='$e_password'";

try{
  $db = new PDO($dsn,$user,$psw);
  echo "it's working!\n";
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo "Error :" . $e."\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using?

Comment: @Blender no i have once tried this with  Postgresql database not working than i tried with sql

Comment: @Daedalus ,null , blender what should i do ???

Comment: -1 Very non-specific, no error message, no versions, unclear wording, no sign of research effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This a bug in php ( [no Bug #62479](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62479)) that When you try to connect to a Postgresql database with a password containing 1 or more spaces, pdo will fail to connect

you have to use like  `goget2me` (No space in password )

Comment: @Daedalus Remedied by revised question, by the looks. Also, seriously, PDO seems scarier every time I see a question on it. Nicely done working out what was going on from this question NullPointer :-)

Comment: It looks like that not placing it into the DSN but providing it as user-name and pass-word does work.

Comment: @scrolllock you can use `str_replace` php function to remove spaces

Comment: @jhonraymos it isn't about the removing space.. consider a situation where user have a database password having white space then str_replace makes no sense. it will remove the space which will behave lika a character

Comment: @NullPointer In that case you can't anything Because it is a bug.You can remove spaces while inserting it into database so that no future will appear..?